# How to Preserve state of UIView Controller when it come back from Background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation

I have created one login Page which have two uiTextField and Login Button. When you try to login Keyboard hide textfield and button, So I have used below code to move up and down view controller from textfield delegate methods.

```
-(void)animateTextField:(UITextField*)textField up:(BOOL)up
{
    int movementDistance = -130; // tweak as needed
    float movementDuration = 0.3f; // tweak as needed
    int movement = (up ? movementDistance : -movementDistance);
    [UIView beginAnimations: @"animateTextField" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

It works fine. But when i close app by home button and restart again it not preserve view controller position, Keyboard is still display but position of view controller changed to default.

Comment: You should not use static values like `-130`. Rather use general code : [Check this from apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Declare a NSNotification in ViewDidLoad of your View Controller class**,when the application will become active it will call your desire method.

---

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
            {

              [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(refreshViewOnActive:)
                                                     name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                                   object:nil];


        // write rest of your code
            }

 - (void)refreshViewOnActive:(NSNotification *)notification {
       if( [textField isFirstResponder]) // check whether keyboard is open or not / or editing is enabled for your textfeild 
          {
            [self animateTextField:textField up:true]; //call your desired method
          }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, But It is not working because when it come back from background it is not calling viewWillAppear.

Comment: I have tried this one, It is not working. If Keyboard not open and you came from background it change view controller position without requirement.

Comment: @nadim You just have to check whether keyboard is present in screen or not before calling the method, such an easy thing you can't do.  updated the answer, check .

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your answer is correct so I have accepted it, But app preserve uiviewcontroller state when app goes in background and used it when it comes to foreground. This is not the case with my app so I am looking for solution which not required explicit call of Notification. Anyway I really appreciate your help, Thank you.